# JMeter distributed testing with files

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test that is sending zip files to a server, and it is distributed it to 20 other machines.  I have the file to be sent in the same location in the filesystem on each machine.

If I run the test to be distributed, it is possible to have the machines grab the zip from their own file system, rather than sending the zip over the network to each of the machines?

Comment: I believe distributed jmeter instances takes the externally referred files from respective local filesystem only. In my distributed scenarios, I have to explicitly distribute the files to respective nodes in my test setup for the tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter use local file system.
But You could use the following elements to make slaves grab the files on startup:

- [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)
- [Setup Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)

Put OS Process Sampler in Setup Thread Group.

Another option is to use FTP Sampler to grad it through ftp is master has an ftp server.